# IIS URL Rewrite Wrong Port in Generated Links for Email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8.5

I am using ARR on IIS 8.5 with a URL rewrite pointing to a server farm. The backend web sites run on the same machine, but on different ports, i.e. `8102`. Some of the backing web site nodes send emails for email confirmation and those mails contain an activation link that has a wrong port in it (host name is correct). The link has the same port which the web site instance has. But that is a problem since the link is then broken. In the code I am using to generate the link:

```
Url.Action("ConfirmMail", "Account",
                new { userId = user.Id, code = UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id)},
                protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

So the link the users get is `https://correct_hostname:8102/Account/ConfirmMail?.....`
The correct link should be `https://correct_hostname/Account/ConfirmMail?.....` or `https://correct_hostname:443/Account/ConfirmMail?.....`

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the port like this (non-tested code):

```
@Url.Action(
    "ConfirmMail", 
    "Account", 
    new { userId = user.Id, code = UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id)}, 
    protocol: Request.Url.Scheme, 
    Request.Url.Host
)
```

[More information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.String,System.String%29)